# Powershell Need just the values from the function

Tags: function, powershell, return

When I "execute" the GetiLONetwork function, I need the values from the GetLogin function. GetLogin has not been "executed" before. 
Unfortunately $a= GetLogin executes the function.
I don't want the GetLogin function to run.

Any ideas?

```bsh
    function GetLogin {
      [hashtable]$Return = @{}
      #GET Login and password
      if ((Read-Host -Prompt "Do you have only the default iLO Administrator? Press Y") -match "y") {
        $Return.loginDefault = Read-Host -Prompt 'default iLO Login'
        $Return.passwordDefault = Read-Host -Prompt 'default iLO Password'
        $Return.default = 1
        $Return.manual = 1
      }else{
        $Return.loginDefault = Read-Host -Prompt 'default iLO Login'
        $Return.passwordDefault = Read-Host -Prompt 'default iLO Password'
        $Return.loginNew = Read-Host -Prompt 'current iLO Login'
        $Return.passwordNew = Read-Host -Prompt 'current iLO password'
        $Return.default = 0
        $Return.manual = 1
      }
      return $Return
    }

function GetiLoNetwork {
  #iLO Login Daten
  $a = GetLogin
  if($a.manual -eq 1){
    if($a.default -eq 1){
        $login = $a.loginDefault
      $password = $a.passwordDefault    
    }elseif($a.default -eq 0){
      $login = $a.loginNew
      $password = $a.passwordNew         
    }
  }else{
    $b = WriteIloFile
    $login = $b.loginDefault
    $password = $b.passwordDefault
  }
}

    Get-iLoNetwork
```

Comment: What do you mean by `"I need the values from the GetLogin function. GetLogin has not been "executed" before. Unfortunately $a= GetLogin executes the function. I don't want the GetLogin function to run."` Without executing the function, how are you going to store the result in the variable?

Comment: @RanadipDutta 
The variables in GetLogin do not always have to be set.

Comment: Then how are you gonna get the values outside Function -- is that the question? If yes, then you can make the return variable `Global` which will allow you to get the value through out entire the script like `$Global:Return` and you can use `$return` anywhere.

Comment: I don't really understand what your issue is. Is it just because you aren't running Get-iLoNetwork first in order to call on the other function?

Comment: @I.TDelinquent So I try to put it another way. When I start the function GetiLoNetwork, it could be that the function GetLogin or the function WriteiLoFile (I didn't post this function here) was executed before. 
However, I need the varaiables from both function (GetLogin and WriteiLoFile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for describing my question in such a complicated way. 
I found a solution that works for me.

Visit https://www.sharepointsky.com/powershell-global-variable/

```
    [int]$global:default = 
    [string]$global:loginDefault = ""
    [string]$global:loginNew = ""

function GetLogin{
    #GET Login and password
    if ((Read-Host -Prompt "Do you have only the default iLO Administrator? Press Y") -match "y") {
        $global:loginDefault = Read-Host -Prompt 'default iLO Login'
        $global:default = 1
    }else{
        $global:loginDefault = Read-Host -Prompt 'default iLO Login'
        $global:loginNew = Read-Host -Prompt 'current iLO Login'
        $global:default = 1
      }
}

function WriteiLoFile{
    $global:default = 0 
    $global:loginDefault ="test"
}

function GetiLoNetwork{
    if($global:default -eq 1){
    $login = $global:loginDefault
    }else{
    $login = $global:loginDefault
    }
}
```